# how can I determine a value's 'stability' in a pandas' column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a columns with data like this:

```
[ 0, +1, +1, +1, 0, +1, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, +1, +1, -1, +1, +1, +1, +1, +1, +1, +1, 0]
```

and I would like the following output:

```
[ 0, +1, +1, +1, 0,  0,  0,  0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1,  0,  0,  0, +1, +1, +1, +1, +1, +1, +1, 0]
```

let me explain:

in the source column, data can be +1, -1 or 0.

in the output, the +1s and -1s that have 3, or more, sequential occurrences can stay; the ones that do not, have to get converted to 0.

I have no idea how to make this as a vector operation. I guess I could start to compare each value with the previous one with something like:

```
groupby(data.eq(data.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount()
```

but I don't know how to build the output sequence.

I'm a light user of Pandas, and I am not well versed in the tools available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Form consecutive groups by checking whether the shifted Series is not equal to itself and taking the `cumsum` and calculate the size of each.

Then keep only zero groups or groups above your threshold and zero the rest (`where` + `fillna`).

```
l = [0,1,1,1,0,1,-1,-1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]

s = pd.Series(l)
m = s.groupby(s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()).transform('size')
s = s.where(s.eq(0) | m.ge(3)).fillna(0).astype(int)

s.tolist()
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

---

Or because in this case your filling value is the same as the one you don't want to change:

```
s = s.where(s.groupby(s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()).transform('size').ge(3), 0)
```

Comment: why not `s.where(s.groupby(s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()).transform('size').ge(3),0)`?

Comment: @ansev yeah in this case checking `s.eq(0)` is unnecessary as the filling is with the same value so that `where` simplifies it :D.  But in general you could perhaps have a different fill value, or could only want to zero out small streaks of `-1`(as opposed to +1 and -1) and I think this makes it a bit clearer how to adopt

Comment: I understand that point of view but perhaps it is also good to point out compact solutions that take full advantage of Pandas' resources.

Comment: memory usage is definitely something I gloss over. Both methods should be nearly indistinguishable in their speed, but perhaps the latter option winds up garbage collecting the size series instead of `m` which sits around in memory on my end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `rolling`:

```
s = s.rolling(3).mean()
s = s.where(s.isin([1, -1])).bfill(limit=2).fillna(0).astype(int)

print(s.tolist())
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```